# How to pass a hidden field value from one controller to another controller using Asp.net MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, view, hidden-field

I am trying to pass a hidden field value from a view in one controller to another controller. I tried the below code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart","Cart"))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="testName" value= @model[0].tblProd[0].ProductName />
}
```

and tried to retrieve that code in a controller called "Cart" as follows:

```
public ViewResult AddToCart(FormCollection collection1)
        {
            string prodName = Request["testName"];
            return View();
        }
```

But it's not work. Can someone assist me in solving this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a form is submitted, the values are sent to the server using the `name` property.

In your example the `input` only has an `id`.

Try:

```
<input type="hidden" id="testName" name="testName" value= @model[0].tblProd[0].ProductName />
```

Also, you can let default model binding take care of reading the POSTed values and setting properties for you so you don't have to do it manually with `Request["testName"]`:

```
public ViewResult AddToCart(FormCollection collection1, string testName)
```